# AJAX GET Request to API(Same origin policy does not apply)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an attempt to do a `GET` through an AJAX request towards an API. I am aware of the `same origin` policy. But the web service gave me a special API key to perform the GET AJAX request to the API. The problem is that I am not getting either a `alert(data)` success or `alert(boom)` error. Nothing is being displayed. The jquery function is taking the value from the textbox and then using that data to perform the api call.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timer = null;
    var $new_result=$("#entry");
    var $api = $new_result.data('url',$new_result.val());

    function submitForm( input ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $api,
            success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("boom");
                    }
        });
        return false
    }

    $("#entry").on("change", function() {
        var input = $(this).val();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
             submitForm(input) ;
        }, 1000);
    })
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="entry" name="entry" style="width: 1000px;" value="http://somesite.com/apikey?123658744sdfs88f7></br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look correct at all:

```
var $new_result=$("#entry");
var $api = $new_result.data('url',$new_result.val());
```

Rather, if you want to get the value from the input, as you stated, you should use the following:

```
var api = $("#entry").val();
```

Unless you've explicitly set the `url` value on the `data` object on that `input` somewhere else in your code, nothing is going to exist there, which may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Alright, I agree. But it is still no success or error being displayed